# Generate code from OpenAPI spec including examples and descriptions

Tags: java, kotlin, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

Suppose I have an OpenAPI spec `.yaml` file with the following properties:

```
.... 
My_Model:
  description: 'Model to do some work'
  type: object
....
```

When I generate it to Kotlin code, using [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage), it is adding the description into Javadoc part:

```
/**
 * Model to do some work
 */

data class MyModel(
....
```

What I want from generator is to add the description into swagger annotation *also* (or *only*):

```
....
@Schema(description = "Model to do some work")
data class MyModel(
....
```

Is there any setting or another generator library/software supporting this?
The same case is true not only for description, but also for examples. Need to work for fields too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `@Schema` annotation in a class level and a property level:

```
@Schema(name = "MyDto", description = "MyDto Model")
class MyDto {
    @Schema(description = "Prop Description", example = "Prop Example")
    var prop: String? = null
    
    @Schema(description = "Text Description", example = "Text Example")
    var text: String? = null
   
    @Schema(description = "Something Description", example = "Something Example")
    var something: String? = null
}
```

---

#### Dependency for `springdoc-openapi-kotlin`:

Using Gradle:

```
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:1.5.9")
```

Using Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-kotlin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.9</version>
</dependency>
```

---

#### Reference:

How to document a Kotlin/Spring application with Springdoc and OpenAI:

- https://www.davideaversa.it/blog/document-kotlin-spring-application-springdoc-openapi/
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-kotlin

Comment: The question is how to generate the schema annotation from the `.yaml` file.